# Qual é a tradução de "as the countryside flashed by"

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

Estou lendo o livro *Prague Winter* de Madeleine Albright.

Um político está viajando de trem pelo interior da Rússia:

> As the countryside flashed by, he had an opportunity to view what little was left of cities and villages, ...

“Enquanto o interior passava”? Muito literal?

Comment: "Como a zona rural passou em relances, ele teve uma oportunidade de ver o pouco que restava de cidades e aldeias" , flashed by seria 'como um raio', mas não cabe na frase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encontramos ***a paisagem desfilava*** e ***a paisagem corria*** em vários livros em situações parecidas. Eu gosto particularmente de *desfilava*, porque dá a ideia da paisagem como um desfile que se apresenta aos olhos do passageiro. Poderás acrescentar um *velozmente* ou advérbio equivalente para dar a ideia de rapidez de *flash*. ***Campos*** ou ***campo*** é possivelmente uma tradução mais literal de *countryside*, mas, tal como o ANeves, eu prefiro *paisagem*, e é o que se encontra na literatura.

Mas para isto soar bem em português precisamos de mais qualquer coisa, como ***a paisagem desfilava lá fora*** ou com um dativo ético, ***a paisagem desfilava-lhe à janela***, se não o leitor poderia pensar, “desfila onde” ou “corre onde”?

Quanto à construção *as [...] he had [...]*, eu experimentaria uma tradução mais livre, como

> A paisagem desfilava-lhe à janela, dando-lhe a oportunidade de ver
>
> A paisagem desfilava-lhe à janela, mostrando-lhe

Alguns exemplos na literatura (ênfase minha):

[image]

> O trem devorava distâncias rumo a São Paulo. [...] À sua frente, à frente dos seus olhos, ***a paisagem desfilava*** num vazio interminável. [[Dário Tavares, *Interrogação*, 1967.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=hIZVAAAAMAAJ&q=%22paisagem%20desfilava%22&dq=%22paisagem%20desfilava%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixstjAxZjNAhXCuRQKHfYDDRwQ6AEIUDAH)
>
> [...] foi se sentar do outro lado do ônibus, num local mais seguro. [...] ***A paisagem corria*** lá fora e Raimundo procurou em vão se concentrar nela: casas de blocos e telhas de amianto, borracharias, crianças batendo bola [[Roberto Schima, *Limbografia*, 2009.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=v-FJBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&dq=%22paisagem%20corria%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXxJPg-pjNAhVrKsAKHSDgCJUQ6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=%22paisagem%20corria%22&f=false)
>
> ***A paisagem corria***, mostrando de vez em vez estaçõeszinhas humildes, com gente velha emponchada junto aos muros. Ficavam para trás velhas taipas com lavouras, laranjais abandonados. [[Raul Bopp, *Putirum*, 1968.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=fokwAQAAIAAJ&q=%22paisagem%20corria%22&dq=%22paisagem%20corria%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXxJPg-pjNAhVrKsAKHSDgCJUQ6AEIbTAL)

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção poderia ser

> Enquanto via a paisagem passar, teve oportunidade de ver quão pouco sobrava de cidades e aldeias, ...

Mas isto perde a noção de «passar rapidamente» que o verbo `flash by` tem.